# Can we find a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n\to 0$, $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is bounded, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Can we find a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n\to 0$, the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is bounded, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Clearly, $a_n$ should be sign changing, if $a_n=(-1)^n b_n$, then $b_n$ is not monotone. But still I could not fix an example.

? Or we could not find such an example?

Comment: Yes.  If $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent, then some rearangment $b_n$ of $a_n$ has the property $\limsup_n \sum_{k=1}^n b_k = 7$ and $\liminf_n\sum_{k=1}^n b_k = 3$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: Close to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: you need to start accepting answers to your questions.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint :** Take $(a_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ the sequence
$$1, -\dfrac{1}{2}, -\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{1}{3}, -\dfrac{1}{4},-\dfrac{1}{4},-\dfrac{1}{4},-\dfrac{1}{4}, \dfrac{1}{5}, \dfrac{1}{5}, \dfrac{1}{5}, \dfrac{1}{5}, \dfrac{1}{5},...$$